# CloudStack on Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install CloudStack on Ubuntu 20.04 focal. After command `apt-get install cloudstack-management` this happens.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cloudstack-management : Depends: python-mysql.connector but it is not installable
                        Depends: libmysql-java but it is not installable
Unable to correct problems, you have broken packages.
```

I tried install CloudStack with aptitude, but not work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was stuck on this,

I'm not precisely sure but I passed by this by downloading:

1. Downloading: [python-mysql.connector](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mysql-connector-python/python-mysql.connector_2.1.6-1_all.deb)
2. run : sudo dpkg -i python-mysql.connector_2.1.6-1_all.deb
3. `apt-get install cloudstack-management`
4. it gave errors and suggested me to run: `sudo apt- --fix-broken install`
   This showed :

> Setting up python-mysql.connector (2.1.6-1) ...

5. then I ran: `apt-get install cloudstack-management` again
6. Install was now going as planned.

so. yeah, hope this helps.